# Как присвоить элементу класс, равный его data-атрибуту (jQuery)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, frontend

Немного погуглив, написал небольшую функцию, которая присваивает элементу новый класс, равный его data-атрибуту. В данном случае реализовал присвоение классу дочернему элементу, при клике на его родителя.

Функция работает, проблем нет, но хочется увидеть, как эту функцию написали-бы люди с опытом...

Грубо говоря, как-бы Вы написали данную функцию?

```css
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown').click(function () {
        var dropdown_list = $('.dropdown_list');
        dropdown_list.addClass(dropdown_list.attr('data-test'));
    })
});
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  dropdown
  <div class="dropdown_list" data-test="test123">dropdown_list</div>
</div>
```

Comment: `var dropdown_list = $(this).find('.dropdown_list'); dropdown_list.addClass(dropdown_list.data('test'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На опытного не претендую, но написал бы так.

```js
$(function () {
    $('.dropdown').click(function () {
       $(this).find('.dropdown_list').each(function(){
        $(this).addClass($(this).data('test'));
       });
    })
});
```

```css
.test123{
  color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="dropdown">
  <span>dropdown</span>
  <div class="dropdown_list" data-test="test123">dropdown_list</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Для чего Вы здесь используете `.each`? Если я не ошибаюсь, то `.find` выбираем по умолчанию всех потомков. Для выборки одного элемента вроде используют `.children`...

Comment: Неа, `children` ищет только непосредственных потомков, а `find` всех. `each` вызывает функцию присвоения класса для каждого элемента набора.

Answer (score 1):

.find для быстродействия (чтобы искать не по всему DOM, а только по элементу события) и .toggleClass, чтобы не дублировать класс после повторных кликов

```
var dropdown_list = $(this).find('.dropdown_list');
dropdown_list.toggleClass(dropdown_list.attr('data-test'))
```

Comment: `чтобы не дублировать класс после повторных кликов` - addClass вроде не создает дублей классов...